# Proof that $[[D^2,f],f]=2[D,f]^2$

Tags: dirac-operator

Let $E$ be a Clifford module with Clifford multiplication $c$. On page 117 of [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) it is claimed that "any operator satisfying
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\forall f \in C^\infty (M):[D, f] = c(df)
\end{equation}
is a Dirac operator" (i.e. such a $D$ is odd and $D^2$ is a generalized Laplacian). The key observation is the following identity:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\forall f \in C^\infty (M):[[D^2,f],f]=2[D,f]^2
\end{equation}
I tried to simply write out the commutators and repeatedly use $(1)$, but I soon realized that I would be facing a crazy amount of terms and according to the authors there is a smarter way to prove $(2)$:

They say that to derive $(2)$ they "have used the fact that that $[[D, f], f] = 0$ and that $[D, [D, A]] = [D^2, A]$ for any odd operator $D$ and even operator $A$".

I do not see how the last two inline equations help us to derive $(2)$, can someone perhaps help me put the pieces together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for an odd operator $B$ we have $[B, B] = BB - (-1)^{|B||B|}BB = 2B^2$. Therefore, we can deduce $(2)$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
[[D^2, f], f] &= [[D, [D, f]], f]\\
&=-[f, [D, [D, f]]]\\
&= -[[f, D], [D, f]] - [D, [f, [D, f]]]\\
&= [[D, f], [D, f]] + [D, \underbrace{[[D, f], f]}_{0}]\\
&= 2[D, f]^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Another way to interpret this calculation is as an application of the super-Jacobi identity for super-commutators.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić: I used the super-Jacobi identity in the third equality. Do you mean the other version of the super-Jacobi identity (i.e. the first one [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/249265/21564))?

Comment: Since $D$ is odd and $f$ is even we can replace all super-commutators with commutators and anti-commutators and we obtain a proof that also works if $D$ is not odd (or if no grading is given). This is relevant because $(1)$ alone does not imply that $D$ is odd.